# Changing the invoicenumber when executing a payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Is it possible to execute a payment and give a new invoice number after a confirmation page? So that the workflow would look like this:

1. Create a payment and redirect the user to paypal's approval link (with intent = sale).
2. The user is redirected back to my shop and sees a confirmation page.
3. After clicking on a confirmation button I execute the previously created payment.

In step 3 I want to add the final invoice number, but I couldn't find an option for this. Or is this workflow not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug at the PayPal sandbox, now everything works. If you want to update a payment before it's executed you can use \PayPal\Api\Patch and \PayPal\Api\PatchRequest.